# Sharepoint Designer XSLT count boolean node = true

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a SharePoint list I converted to XSLT to do some additional grouping and counting and percentages.  I need to return the number of items = true within my nodeset, I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall)"/>
```

(which returns the count of all the nodes)

I have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall
                                        [@PartnerArrivedAtCall = 'Yes'])"/>
```

(returns zero)

and

```
<xsl:variable name="ArrivedYes"
              select="$nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall
                                  [@PartnerArrivedAtCall='Yes']"/>
```

(also returns zero)

Can you please give me a good example of how to count only the true values (in my XML, true = "Yes")

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
count($nodeset[@PartnerArrivedAtCall = 'Yes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use out of the box `ddwrt` namespace functions to return list property: `itemCount`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx#officesharepointddwrt_listproperty

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried xsl:value-of
>   select="count($nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall[@PartnerArrivedAtCall
>   = 'Yes')" (returns zero)

Yes, this is correct: an attribute cannot have attributes itself -- in the above you want to count `PartnerArrivedAtCall` attributes whose `PartnerArrivedAtCall` attribute has a specific value.

.
.

> and xsl:variable name="ArrivedYes"
>   select=
>   "$nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall[@PartnerArrivedAtCall='Yes']"
>
> (also returns zero)

This has exactly the same problem as the previous instruction.

**Solution**:

Use:

```
$nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall[. ='Yes']
```

Comment: That way all matching attrs will be counted. Though there is no difference due to the wellformedness constraints. Just interesting style, catched my eye.

Comment: @Flack: It isn't clear from the question what exactly he wants counted -- seems he wants to count the attributes ...

Comment: @Flack and @Dimitre: In fact, for this case the count will be the same for `$nodeset/@PartnerArrivedAtCall[. ='Yes']` and `$nodeset[@PartnerArrivedAtCall='Yes']`

Comment: @Alejandro, that's why I said there is no difference ;)